# Is there a way to get complete html content of pages in bulk in sitefinity?

Tags: sitefinity

I need to extract the HTML content from different pages and put them in XML file. Is there a way to get complete HTML content from child pages of a group page in Sitefinity?

Comment: By HTML content you mean, whole page html? Kind of "Ctrl + S" in the browser?

Comment: Extracting innerHTML of certain div would be ideal for my case but the whole page will also work. I can use other tools to extract a particular section from it.

Comment: I think http://www.httrack.com/ will suit for you. It's a free and easy-to-use offline browser utility. It will just crape whole website to folder, then you process their HTML as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the page nodes you need with the Sitefinity API, loop through them and do a GET request, e.g. by using WebClient() and DownloadString method.
Then do whatever you wish with the html string.